# Linq to XML - Problem selecting elements

Tags: linq-to-xml

```
<Invoice type='Component' displayName='Invoice' pluralName='Invoices' Msgversion='1' version='1'>
  <UserData type='SpecialElement'>
    <Something />
  </UserData>
  <From type='SpecialElement'>
    <Something />
  </From>
  <To type='SpecialElement'>
    <Something />
  </To>
  <CdtDbtNoteAmt type='xsd:decimal' />
  <PmtDueDt type='xsd:date' />
  <Adjstmnt>
    <AdjAmt />
    <Rate />
  </Adjstmnt>
  <CpyDplct type='PickList'>
    <Item Text='Copy Duplicate' Value='CODU' />
    <Item Text='Copy' Value='COPY' />
    <Item Text='Duplicate' Value='DUPL' />
  </CpyDplct>
  <InvItems type='ParentElement'>
    <InvGd type='Element'>
      <GdDesc type='xsd:decimal' />
      <QtyVl type='xsd:decimal' />
      <ChrgAmt type='xsd:decimal' />
      <PrceVl type='xsd:decimal' />
    </InvGd>
  </InvItems>
</Invoice>
```

Hi,

I need to get elements where

- the type attribute is not SpecialElement or PickList
- there are child elements
- the type attribute of the parent is not ParentElement

So, based on the XML snippet I want to get the Adjstmnet and InvGd elements.

The closest I can get is

```
var query = from n in xe.Elements()
        let attributeType = n.Attribute("type").Value
        where attributeType != "SpecialElement"
        where attributeType != "PickList"
        where n.HasElements
        select n;
```

but that doesn't include the InvGd element.

Any ideas on what I need to change/add?

Thanks,

David

Comment: Crap. The editor mangled my XML snippet. How do I get it to include the whole snippet and maintain indentation?

Comment: You need to be a little bit clearer... what is `InvGd` for example? Show a complete small example and the expected output.

Comment: I'm sorry I wasn't clear. 
I basically need to get a list that contains only 2 elements, the Adjstmnet element 
(<Adjstmnt><AdjAmt /><Rate /></Adjstmnt>) 
and the InvGd element 
(<InvGd type='Element'><GdDesc type='xsd:decimal' /><QtyVl type='xsd:decimal' /><ChrgAmt type='xsd:decimal' /><PrceVl type='xsd:decimal' /></InvGd>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xe.Descendants()` instead of `xe.Elements()` should help. Of course you also need to add the check about the parent element.

```
var query = from el in xe.Descendants()
            let attType = (string)el.Attribute("type")
            let parentType = (string).el.Parent.Attribute("type")
            where attType != "SpecialElement" && attType != "PickList"
                  && el.HasElements
                  && parentType != "ParentElement"
            select el
```

Comment: Thanks very much Martin, that seems to do the job